# Extracting only relevant item from json blob in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

I am quite new on JSR223 which I have been trying out. I have a use case when an item which are `available=true` only I want to grab `id` and ignoring out of stock item from below JSON blob. Can someone please advise?

```
"items": {
    "104": {
        "id": "104",
        "stock": {
            "available": true,
            "lowOnStock": false,
            "quantity": 11
        },
    },
    "105": {
        "id": "105",
        "stock": {
            "available": false,
            "lowOnStock": true,
            "quantity": 0
        },
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: I was trying via json extractor adding jsonpath with condition to filter out available but I was stuck on how to get ID for available=true

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to avoid scripting where possible so you can go for [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) and the following [JSONPath query](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath):

```
$..[?(@.stock.available==true)].id
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I think this approach would work. I'll try it out.

Comment: is it possible to grab `id` if stock was an array for condition `stock.available=true`? I basically want to grab elements outside the array after condition is fulfilled.